# Scala type projection: pick an object within a path-dependent trait

Tags: scala, path-dependent-type, type-projection

I have a path-dependent trait declaring several modules. That is fine. However, I write a macro and I need to access those inner types and I am unable to write a proper expression selecting them.

```
trait A {

  type Foo

  object module { // one  of modules encapsulating functionality

     class Bar // I use it as an annotation depending on Foo but that is irrelevant
  }

  class Other
}
```

Now I need to write a proper type expression selecting the `Bar` class to retrieve its `weakTypeTag`. I am able to write `weakTypeOf[ A#Other ]` to select the `Other` class. But when I try to select `Bar` it does not work. I tried:

- `A#module.Bar`
- `A#module#Bar`
- `A#module.type.Bar`
- `A#module.type#Bar`

All these fail at the `module` selection.

Why do not these work and how make them working? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`module` is an **object** inside `A`, (it depends on instance of `A`), so this object `A` should be reflected in its type signature:

```
scala> typeOf[a.module.type forSome { val a: A }]
res1: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = a.module.type forSome { val a: A }
```

you can see this by creating alias `Inner` inside of trait `A`

```
trait A {
  type Inner = module.type // it is actually this.module.type, where this refers to the instance of A
  object module {
    class Bar
  }
}
```

now we can check that these two types are equivalent:

```
scala> typeOf[A#Inner]
res2: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = _8.module.type forSome { val _8: A }

scala> res1 =:= res2
res3: Boolean = true
```

Finally, to access innermost `Bar`, we need to add appropriate projection:

```
scala> implicitly[(a.module.type forSome { val a: A })#Bar =:= A#Inner#Bar]
res4: =:=[a.module.Bar,_38.module.Bar] = <function1>
```

Comment: Thanks, great answer! So basically, with `A#module.type#Bar` I was right. It just doesn't work this way as there is missing something like parentheses, right? That is the reason why I have to explicitly define the type alias, isn't that? (accept and +1)

Comment: It is a good observation. AFAIK in general, type projection is not equal to existential type. Given your hierarchy, `implicitly[A#Other =:= (a.Other forSome { val a: A })]` gives error. While `A#Inner` looks like type projection, in fact it represents existential type, and equality holds.